# Mongoose: Missing expected field "$search"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to execute a query which performs a full text search with mongoose. The filter object looks as follows and works using `mongosh`:

```js
{
  authorUid: 'X',
  '$text': { '$search': 'searchStr' }
}
```

But, whenever trying to execute this with mongoose, I'm getting the following error:

```
MongoServerError: Missing expected field "$search"
```

The mongoose code is as follows:

```js
let query = Collection.find(
    filterObj,
    {
        _id: 1,
        title: 1,
        src: 1,
    },
    { sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
);
```

I am quite certain the text search index in the collection is created without error. It is visible in MongoDB Compass and I don't think the query should have worked in `mongosh` if this wasn't the case.
To be complete, here is the command ran via `mongosh`:

```js
db.collection.find(
  {
    authorUid: 'X',
    '$text': { '$search': 'searchStr' }
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    title: 1,
    src: 1
  },
  {sort: {createdAt: -1}}
)
```

Is this one not equivalent with the one written for Mongoose? How can I perform this query using Mongoose?

**-- EDIT --**
Just to ensure the cause is not the `filterObj`, I tried doing the exact same thing with it hard coded. Using Mongoose, it looks as follows:

```js
let query = Collection.find(
  {
     $text: {
        $search: "math",
      },
  },
);
```

I'm still getting the same error. It is however still working via `mongosh`.

**-- EDIT 2 --**
I did get this to work using aggregates instead of `.find`. The following code returns the same as in the `mongosh` environment:

```js
const res = await Collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
           $text: {
                $search: "math",
            },
        },
    },
]);
```

This is most definitely usable, but I'm still clueless as to why the initial query did not work.

Comment: One comment is that the sort is in the wrong place - it is not an argument to the find() method. But I don't really think there's enough information here to say anything definitive about your main problem directly. You suggest that `filterObj` is equivalent to the shell testing you are doing, but do you have any logging to help confirm that?

Comment: I tried this without the sort as well and it did not make a difference unfortunately. About the `filterObj`, I logged this in my nodejs application and copied that output as the input for the command in `mongosh` so I’m certain both are equivalent.